# Is there a nice Javascript arithmetic-only addition operator?

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-overloading, addition

By this I mean NOT the default javascript behavior of string + number = string, or string + string = string. From http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/arithmetic_operators.shtml, the Unary plus will convert a string to a number.

So how would I specify that I want numeric addition with two strings? This seems to work, but is somewhat ugly:

```
var a = "5";
var b = "2";
var c = +a + +b;
```

Does there exist a (numeric only +) operator, that always returns a number? Can one be defined like in other languages? For examples, perhaps '%%' or '+^' or '+++'? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to perform numeric addition than you have to ensure that both sides of the expression are Numbers before you start.

Comment: No there isn't one and No you can't define your own operators (like in C# or Java for example)?